# Custom model binding for generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a ASP.Net MVC 4 app where I'm trying to create a custom model binder. The model it has to deal is this:

```
public class CompressedJsonViewModel<T>
    where T : ViewModel
```

To receive it as a param in the Action as:

```
public ActionResult ImportData(CompressedJsonViewModel<ImportDataViewModel> input)
```

And (for now) I have a simple binder, which I will improve when the config is fine:

```
public class CompressedJsonModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

The problem starts here. If the `CompressedJsonViewModel` is not set as generic, the below assignment to model binders works:

```
binders.Add(typeof(CompressedJsonViewModel), new CompressedJsonModelBinder());
```

But when I add the generic `T` to the class signarture, the `BindModel` method is not called anymore. I can't figure out how to set the right binding. I tried two things:

1. Binding as

   ```
   binders.Add(typeof(CompressedJsonViewModel<>), new CompressedJsonModelBinder());
   ```
2. Creating an interface as `CompressedJsonViewModel : ICompressedJsonViewModel` and set the binding to it as

   ```
   binders.Add(typeof(ICompressedJsonViewModel), new CompressedJsonModelBinder());
   ```

Both didn't works. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45625359/1267304) but it seems somewhat overkill to me. I would like to avoid using something like `[ModelBinder(typeof(CompressedJsonModelBinder))]` in the parameters, I would like to make something more *automatic* than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `ModelBinderProvider`:

```
public class CompressedJsonBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
   public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
   {
       if(!modelType.IsGenericType)
            return null;

       var genericType =  modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

       if(genericType == typeof(CompressedJsonViewModel<>))
           return new CompressedJsonModelBinder();

       return null;        
   }
}
```

By the way, this shows you the mechanics, but I'd also cache te=he type check in to avoid having to do the type reflection on every single request.