# Is there any way to have an endpoint using generics in a WebAPI with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net

With .net core and newton JSON. Can I have an endpoint using generics? How should I request it to pass the generic type?

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveSetting<T>([FromBody] Filter<T> model)
{}

public class Filter<T>
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FilterType FilterType { get; set; }

    public T FilterRequestModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to build your own model binder for this. One that determines which type to build based on the data.

Comment: do you know any place where I can find samples for that?

Comment: How would you expect this to work?  You don't resolve generics at runtime, you resolve them at compile time.  All you need is to replace type T with a JObject.

Comment: is this close to what you want to achieve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239364/dot-net-core-custom-model-binding-for-generic-type-parameters-in-mvc-action-meth

Comment: like @DavidL said. Just accept JSON directly.

Comment: Like that? public async Task<JsonResult> SaveSetting([FromBody] Filter<JObject> model)
{}

Comment: The type is literally `JObject`.   `public async Task<JsonResult> SaveSetting([FromBody] Filter<JObject> model) {}`.  It is a tree-based object that you can dynamically walk if you need to, or serialize into any number of types based on your needs.  You can attach metadata at the top level to tell you what kind of type to deserialize into.

Comment: But doing that I will need to solve the JObject inside this method, wouldn't be better to have a custom binder like the example @Sharif sent?

Comment: @Nestorzin that model binder won't work.  You still have to provide the generic type *somewhere* to get your code to compile.  In your example, you are expecting the type to be sent from the client which will never compile, model binder or not.

A model binder allows you to declare a generic type model that is then strongly typed at each site.  You don't have anything like that in your example.  If you wanted to use a model binder to encapsulate the deserialization you certainly could and then the model would be usable across multiple endpoints, but that defeats your example.

Comment: I'm thinking about not using any generic and use only the JObject, what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that there's an *easy* way to make this work, if there's a way at all. More importantly, it would be highly inadvisable. Presumably you'd need to figure out what type `T` should be based on input from the UI, and then you'd be binding values to that type with JSON bindings. That means you'd be allowing the caller (who you cannot trust) to make your code instantiate and set properties on a C# type of their choosing, which represents [a security vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection).

There's a good chance you can make this endpoint do what you want without generics: just use a JObject as the FilterRequestModel object. If you really do rely on actual C# types to accomplish what you want, you're still better off making your controller action use a `JObject`, and using some custom logic to translate it based on some user input, after checking that the type specified is something you want callers to be able to instantiate. Once you've created an object of a custom type, you can cast it to `dynamic` before passing it into a generic helper method, and the generic type will automatically be resolved at runtime to the type of the object you created.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveSetting([FromBody] Filter<JObject> model)
{
    Type filterRequestModelType = this.DetermineSafeModelType(model);
    object typedFilterRequestModel = model.FilterRequestModel.ToObject(filterRequestModelType);
    return SaveSettingHelper(model, (dynamic) typedFilterRequestModel);
}

public async Task<JsonResult> SaveSetting<T>([FromBody] Filter<JObject> model, T filterRequestModel) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm thinking about getting rid any generic type and have a model like this:

```public class Filter
{
    public string GUID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FilterType FilterType { get; set; }

    public JObject FilterRequestModel { get; set; }
}```

What do you think?

Comment: I think that's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

.NET CLI

```
dotnet new web --name "GenericApiExample"
cd GenericApiExample
dotnet add package SingleApi
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

// map generics endpoint
app.MapSingleApi("sapi", 
    // add your generic request handler
    // for example, return the received data (already typed object)
    x => Task.FromResult(x.Data), 
    // add assemblies for resolving received data types
    typeof(List<>).Assembly, typeof(int).Assembly);

app.Run();
```

Example request, equivalent of Dictionary<string,int?[]>

```
POST /sapi/Dictionary(String-Array(Nullable(Int32)))
{"key1":[555,null,777]}
```

[GitHub repository with examples](https://github.com/mustaddon/SingleApi)